# Collapse effect doesn't work with ng-hide

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

On a project, I use Angularjs 1.3.6 and Bootstrap 3.1.1.

I display the content of an array on two columns with `ng-repeat` (with some filters) and `ng-hide` :

```
<div class="first-col">
        <div class="formation-panel" ng-repeat="formation in formations | filter:formationType | filter:search | formationsAnnee:this" ng-hide="$index%2">
            @formation()
        </div>
</div>

<div class="second-col">
        <div class="formation-panel" ng-repeat="formation in formations | filter:formationType | filter:search | formationsAnnee:this" ng-hide="($index+1)%2">
            @formation()
        </div>
</div>
```

The `@formation()` syntax comes from Play Framework. It renders the following content :

```
<div class="formation-panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#formation-body-{{formation.id}}">
          ...Heading...
</div>
<div class="formation-panel-body" id="formation-body-{{formation.id}}">
        ...Some content...
</div>
```

(I attribute the collapsed class to the heading with the Less mixin)

The elements displayed in the two columns are Bootstrap panels. I want to apply a collapsing effect on those panels: the body has to collapse when we click on the heading.
It works well on the first column but not at all on the second.

For me, it makes no sense. Any idea of the cause of that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't solved the problem of coexistence between Angular `ng-hide` and the Bootstrap collapse effect, but I achieved to render the feature with `ng-show` : I affected a `show` attribute, initialized to `false`, to my objects displayed by `ng-repeat`.
The heading becomes :

```
<div class="formation-panel-heading" ng-click="formation.show=!formation.show">...</div>
```

And the body :

```
<div class="formation-panel-body" ng-show="formation.show">
```